# Como recarregar dados em uma tableview sem perder os dados anteriores (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Olá, eu tenho um tableview que vai receber dados por demanda. porem quando eu chamo a função scrollViewDidEndDragging que tem uma chamada para o tableview.reloadData() ele substitui os dados carregados anteriormente.

Carrega Dados

```
func carregaDados(pagina : Int)
{
    let pg : String = String(pagina)
    liberaLoad = false
    var url : String = "minha url json rest"
    var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler: { (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let jsonResult : NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
        if(jsonResult != nil){
            //process json
            let jsonUnico: NSMutableArray! = jsonResult["lista"] as? NSMutableArray
            self.tableList = jsonUnico
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.liberaLoad = true
        }else{
            //nao foi possivel ler o json
        }

    })     
}
```

Aqui eu tenho a função que era para dar um append nos dados

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    let currentOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    let maximumOffset : CGFloat = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= -60.0 && liberaLoad) {
        self.carregaDados(pagina:2)
    }
}
```

Aqui meu cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustonImageTableViewCell
    let reeditList : NSMutableDictionary = self.tableList[indexPath.row] as NSMutableDictionary

    let tipo = reeditList["tipo"] as? String
    cell.lblTipo.text = tipo
    return cell

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, Consegui da seguinte maneira.
Utilizei como base principal o NSMutableArray porem ao invés de utilizar addObject eu usei o meuArray.addObjectsFromArray(meuArray)

Com isso no momento de pegar os valores do Array eu posso utilizar o NSMutableDictionary valeu ai pessoal.

att,

Answer (score -1):

Olá, o problema está aqui:

Swift Code:

```
   if(jsonResult != nil){
        //process json
        let jsonUnico: NSMutableArray! = jsonResult["lista"] as? NSMutableArray
        self.tableList = jsonUnico //<-
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.liberaLoad = true
    }else{
```

Se observar a cada vez que recarrega, a fonte de dados é sobrescrita. Isso considerando que self.tablelist é a fonte de dados da tableView.

Dica: Normalmente crio um objeto e a fonte de dados fica como um array desse objeto, pois irá ajudar a quem for trabalhar no código além de dar um contexto a seus dados. Segue exemplo do que quero dizer.

```
//Livro.Swift
class Livro:NSObject {
    var nome = ""

    init(nome: String) {
        self.nome = nome
    }
}

//ViewController que possui a TableView
var fonteDados = [Livro]()

//Quando for buscar por mais livros. 
//Essa é a maneira mais segura! Nunca se sabe o que vem do servidor
if let livros = jsonResult["LIVROS"] as? NSArray {
    for livro in livros {
        if let nome = livro as? String {
            fonteDados.append(Livro(nome: nome))
        }
    }
}

//Para preencher a tableView com "Livros"
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //...
    linha.textLabel?.text = fonteDados[indexPath.row].nome
    //...
}
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.